# Android: Let user pick image or video from Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types

Is it possible to to start Gallery in such a way so both pictures and videos are shown?

Thanks

Comment: Late answer.... Try this for Once
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43385723/7634226

Comment: As Google Photos does not understand more than one type on the intent - try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44336740/3734116

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You start the gallery as such:

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
pickIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
startActivityForResult(pickIntent, IMAGE_PICKER_SELECT);
```

then in your `onActivityResult` you can check if video or image was selected by doing this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri selectedMediaUri = data.getData();
    if (selectedMediaUri.toString().contains("image")) {
        //handle image
    } else  if (selectedMediaUri.toString().contains("video")) {
        //handle video
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok but how do you set selectedMediaUri in the intent?

Comment: `selectedMediaUri.toString().contains("image")` will work instead of that word `images`.

Comment: @Chip, done. @Siavash, should we not check for `requestCode == IMAGE_PICKER_SELECT` in callback, for clarity? many practical activties may have a whole bunch of stuff handled in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: Doesn't work on Android 6.0. It only chooses first filter.

Comment: and hope google wont change that default path naming :)

Answer (score 66):

#### Pick Audio file from Gallery:

```
//Use MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

#### Pick Video file from Gallery:

```
//Use MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

#### Pick Image from gallery:

```
//Use  MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

#### Pick Media Files or images:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("image/* video/*");
```

Comment: after the user picks the media file, and OnResult gets called, How can I tell if the selected file was image or video?

Comment: @Siavash If u found the answer please post here

Comment: @aravindvarma I have posted the answer :)

Comment: Images + videos do not work on Android 5.1, it always shows the files with first mime type. In this case the images. Any ideas?

Comment: Google photos app just takes the first type. Does not work!

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal there two solutions 1) two buttons, one for images, second for videos 2) create own picker

Answer (score 27):

*(EDIT: I don't use it anymore, we went back to the two choices "pick image" and "pick video". The problem was with some Sony phone. So, it's not 100% solution below, be careful! )*

This is what I use:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/* video/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.select_picture)), SELECT_GALLERY);
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"});
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_GALLERY_KITKAT);
}
```

The key here is `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"});`

Comment: I used your method its works but I am unable to read the filePath using MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA column, any idea which one should I use here to it

Comment: Should this read `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"video/*"});` since the type has already been set with `intent.setType("image/*");`?

Comment: Nice solution but does not work on a Nexus 9 with Android 7, the Google photo app shows only the pictures. On other test devices it worked as expected.

Answer (score 11):

```
intent.setType("*/*");
```

This presents user with dialog but works on at least ICS. Haven't tested on other platforms.

Comment: Working for Android 7 Nougat.

Comment: works but will also display a bunch of other random apps like sound/calendar along with video/photo

Answer (score 8):

When you need to determine what kind of content was returned, you can do it using content resolver to get the MIME type of the returned content:

```
if( data != null) {
    Uri selectedUri = data.getData();   
    String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                         MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedUri, columns, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int pathColumnIndex     = cursor.getColumnIndex( columns[0] );
    int mimeTypeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex( columns[1] );

    String contentPath = cursor.getString(pathColumnIndex);
    String mimeType    = cursor.getString(mimeTypeColumnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    if(mimeType.startsWith("image")) {
          //It's an image
    }
    else if(mimeType.startsWith("video")) {
         //It's a video
    }       
}
else {
    // show error or do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Still Working On *Jan'2022***

If This is Working For You Then Try it,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider
                          .MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/* video/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_FILE);
```

else For Older SDK's and For Some Devices Try the below one,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"});
     startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_FILE);
```

**where, ***PICK_FILE*** is a variable,**

```
private static final int PICK_FILE = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

CoolIris which came with my galaxy tab can do it. However the cooliris on my acer betouch will not :S
On my milestone you can not start the gallery with a pick intent on the video url however when you start it on the images url, you can select a video and it will return a video url too.

Answer (score 2):

`UPDATE 2021`

FINALLY a solution working for Android 9.

This piece of code only open image apps, and you can select both images and videos. I tried a bunch of different combinations and this exact code will make it work.

```
    libraryIntent.setType("video/*, image/*");
    String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "video/*"};
    libraryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
```

Comment: Hello, this code only allows me to pick videos. Can you post your whole solution here?

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me for Android 12 (SDK 32)
Pick multiple images & videos from the gallery
Also with the latest **registerForActivityResult**

```
val resultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            onActivityResult(result)
        }

fun pickMediaFiles() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.type = "image/* video/*"
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/*", "video/*"))
        resultLauncher.launch(intent)
    }

fun onActivityResult(result: ActivityResult) {
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {
            //If selected multiple medias
            if (result.data?.clipData != null) {
                val count: Int =
                    result.data!!.clipData!!.itemCount 
                for (i in 0 until count) {
                    val selectedUri: Uri? = result.data!!.clipData?.getItemAt(i)?.uri
                }
            }
            //If selected single media
            else if (result.data?.data != null) {
                val selectedUri: Uri? = result.data?.data
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying out different combinations from above answers and from other questions.
This is what is **finally working** for me. **API levels I tested it on v23 to v34.**
But it should work on versions below and higher too.

```
/**
 * Open gallery intent
 */
private void dispatchGalleryIntent() {
    final Intent openGalleryIntent = getOpenGalleryIntent();
    startActivityForResult(openGalleryIntent, REQ_CHOOSE_GALLERY);
}

/**
 * Returns gallery intent
 */
@NonNull
private Intent getOpenGalleryIntent() {
    final Intent openGalleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    openGalleryIntent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "*/*");
    openGalleryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"});
    openGalleryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    return openGalleryIntent;
}
```

**Key Factors** in the above code is to

1. first define
   type as `"*/*"` {representing All Data Types} and then pass your filters MimeType.
   Like in my case I wanted Video and Images so I passed mimeType array as `{"image/*", "video/*"}"`
2. Use `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` instead of `EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

**CONFIGURATION REQUIREMENTS**

Manifest Permissions Required
**For API Level 32 and lower**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**For API Level 33 and higher**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

> Below is Complete code including checking for permissions and selecting files from GALLERY.
>
> Callbacks after selecting files can be handled in `onActivityResult`

**How to ask for permissions ?** I am using EasyPermissions to check and ask for permissions. But you can use any method or simply use Android Default permission method.

```
private String[] attachmentsPathArr = new String[]{};
private final int REQ_GALLERY_PERMISSION = 300;
private final int REQ_CHOOSE_GALLERY = 600;

@RequiresApi(api = 33)
public static final String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE_AVI_V33_ARR = {        //AVI - Audio, Video, Image
            Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO,
            Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
    };
public static final String PERMISSION_STORAGE = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

 /**
 * Open Gallery task with permission
 */
@AfterPermissionGranted(REQ_GALLERY_PERMISSION)
private void galleryTask() {
    if (hasStoragePermission()) {
        // Have permission, call the gallery intent!
        dispatchGalleryIntent();
    } else {
        // Request one permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.gallery_permission_message),
                    REQ_GALLERY_PERMISSION, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE_AVI_V33_ARR);
        } else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.gallery_permission_message),
                    REQ_GALLERY_PERMISSION, PERMISSION_STORAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

**Permission Check**

```
 /**
 * Storage specific permission check
 */
private boolean hasStoragePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        return EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS_STORAGE_AVI_V33_ARR);
    } else {
        return EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(getActivity(), PERMISSION_STORAGE);
    }
}
```

**Handle/Save selected files path returning from Gallery.**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQ_CHOOSE_GALLERY) {
                showLog(TAG, "onActivityResult REQ_CHOOSE_GALLERY- " + REQ_CHOOSE_GALLERY);
                if (data != null) {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                        attachmentsPathArr = new String[count];  //Initializing the array based on number of files path received
                        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
                            attachmentsPathArr[index] = FileUtils.getPath(getActivity(), data.getClipData().getItemAt(index).getUri());
                            showLog(TAG, "onActivityResult \n -attachmentsPathArr[" + index + "].getUri()- " + data.getClipData().getItemAt(index).getUri());
                        }

                        setSelectedFiles(); //Do your next operation here like displaying the files or saving it.
                    } else {
                        showLog(TAG, "onActivityResult selectedImageUri == null selectedImageUri- " + selectedImageUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
}
```

Hope it helps and saves your time!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need use the following as picking Intent

```
Intent photoLibraryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
photoLibraryIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
```