# call android gallery for both image and video

Tags: android

when i have to get some image or video

i did like this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("video/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent ,  ActNetwork.EXTRA_FLAG_SEARCH_LOCAL_VOD);
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent , ActNetwork.EXTRA_FLAG_SEARCH_LOCAL_VOD);
```

i try to

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/* , video/*");
```

but in occured error

how can i solve that problem..

thanks your reply

Comment: `but in occured error` what do you mean? Give us details of the error please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Let user pick image or video from Gallery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922037/android-let-user-pick-image-or-video-from-gallery)

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
galleryIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I am suing my Samsung Galaxy S3. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("media/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent , ActNetwork.EXTRA_FLAG_SEARCH_LOCAL_VOD);
```

Comment: it has occurred error too                                              08-04 16:15:52.185: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12580): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=media/* }

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Works on 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue and I found the solution.

```
Intent pickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
pickerIntent.setType("image/*, video/*");
pickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"});
startActivityForResult(pickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_FOR_MEDIA);
```

The key here is pickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"});

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("*/*");
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] { "video/* images/*"});
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_GALLERY);
```