# android- open gallery and choose image and video

Tags: android, video, android-gallery

In my project I want to open a gallery on a button click and should be able to pick image or video to get path of them.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

From above code i am able to open gallery but in this case i am only able to choose image. So, please help me in choosing video also.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below code solved my problem

```
  final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        galleryIntent.setType("*/*");
                        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Answer (score 31):

On Android 6.0 and above using "video/* image/*" or "image/* video/*" type doesn't work, it only recognizes the first filter you specify. I solved the problem using this code:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("*/*");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"});
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, Constants.SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Although this will ask the user which app they want to use to select the image/video.

Comment: Thanks, this response should be higher up nowadays

Comment: Exact solution for choose only video and image booth parallel.

Comment: This approach shows extra chooser dialog on android 6.0.1. If choose Google Photos right, it displays videos and photos.

Comment: It displays other apps as well like contacts, google music.

Comment: AS OF 2021 I have added a solution below that allows only for images and videos, I found nothing else online that worked so I mixed some answers and accidentaly found the solution

Answer (score 22):

You can use the next snippet:

```
Intent mediaChooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//comma-separated MIME types
mediaChooser.setType("video/*, image/*");
startActivityForResult(mediaChooser, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

But I think that it only work on ICS or bigger

Comment: should be "image/*" instead of "images/*"

Comment: on 6.0 this only allows videos to be chosen

Comment: This seems to be broken, at least for newer versions of android or google photos app.  Seems like only the first mime type in comma separated list is recognized.

Comment: How can I multi-select photos and videos?

Answer (score 11):

You need use the following as picking Intent

```
Intent photoLibraryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
photoLibraryIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
```

Answer (score 9):

`2022 Android 9`

I've tried everything available online, and accidently mixed 2 solutions that turned out to work.

This only gives photo library and google photos as options, and you can select photos AND videos.

```
    libraryIntent.setType("video/*, image/*");
    String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "video/*"};
    libraryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
```

Answer (score 8):

Not enough rep to comment, but @YYamil's response works well.

```
Intent mediaChooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//comma-separated MIME types
mediaChooser.setType("video/*, image/*");
startActivityForResult(mediaChooser, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

If you're using the new [registerForResultActivity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#register), create a copy of `ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()` and put in `createIntent`:

```
    @CallSuper
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: String): Intent {
        return Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            .setType(input)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/*", "video/*")) // this does the trick
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the best i known...... Try this for once....

```
 final CharSequence[] options = {"Images", "Videos", "Cancel"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OpenGallery.this);
            builder.setTitle("Select From...");
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (options[item].equals("Images")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    } else if (options[item].equals("Videos")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your Intent to this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

When trying to get videos you need to state to mediaStore that video is in order and not images as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Well android has put a lot of restriction on accessing the external content. I ended up using 3rd party library. This one is good.:
https://github.com/AnilFurkanOkcun/UWMediaPicker-Android

```
implementation 'com.github.AnilFurkanOkcun:UWMediaPicker-Android:1.3.0'


UwMediaPicker
.with(this)                     // Activity or Fragment
    .setGalleryMode(UwMediaPicker.GalleryMode.ImageGallery) // GalleryMode: ImageGallery/VideoGallery/ImageAndVideoGallery, default is ImageGallery
.setGridColumnCount(4)                                  // Grid column count, default is 3
    .setMaxSelectableMediaCount(10)                         // Maximum selectable media count, default is null which means infinite
    .setLightStatusBar(true)                                // Is llight status bar enable, default is true
.enableImageCompression(true)               // Is image compression enable, default is false
.setCompressionMaxWidth(1280F)              // Compressed image's max width px, default is 1280
.setCompressionMaxHeight(720F)              // Compressed image's max height px, default is 720
.setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)      // Compressed image's format, default is JPEG
.setCompressionQuality(85)              // Image compression quality, default is 85
.setCompressedFileDestinationPath(destinationPath)  // Compressed image file's destination path, default is "${application.getExternalFilesDir(null).path}/Pictures"
.launch{selectedMediaList-> } // (::onMediaSelected)    // Will be called when media is selected
```

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared a way to use all of the Intents that were used for this across Android versions.

It also allows multiple MimeTypes.

Example for webp/gif: `getGalleryIntent(activity, null, "image/webp|image/gif")`

You need to use try-catch for each of the Intents that you get there, so that you could go to the next fallback if it doesn't work.

You can do the same for images in general together with videos in general.

```
    private fun setTypesForIntent(intent: Intent, type: String = "image/*") {
        val split = type.split('|')
        if (split.size <= 1)
            intent.type = type
        else {
            //            galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, split.toTypedArray())
        }
    }

    fun getGalleryIntent(context: Context, title: CharSequence?, type: String = "image/*", extraIntents: ArrayList<Intent>? = null): Array<Intent> {
        val documentPickerIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        setTypesForIntent(documentPickerIntent, type)
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.Q)
            return arrayOf(getPickImageChooserIntent(context, title, true, type, extraIntents), documentPickerIntent)
        val packageManager = context.packageManager
        val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        setTypesForIntent(galleryIntent, type)
        val galleryChooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, title)!!
        if (!extraIntents.isNullOrEmpty())
            galleryChooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents.toTypedArray<Parcelable>())
        val pickIntent =
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK).setData(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        setTypesForIntent(pickIntent, type)
        val pickChooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, title)!!
        if (!extraIntents.isNullOrEmpty())
            pickChooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents.toTypedArray<Parcelable>())
        val getContentActivities =
                packageManager.queryIntentActivitiesCompat(galleryIntent)
        //avoid using the new picker it possible
        val newFilePickerResolveInfo =
                getContentActivities.firstOrNull { it.activityInfo.packageName == "com.google.android.providers.media.module" }
        if (newFilePickerResolveInfo != null)
            return arrayOf(documentPickerIntent, galleryChooserIntent, galleryIntent, pickChooserIntent, pickIntent)
        return arrayOf(galleryChooserIntent, galleryIntent, pickChooserIntent, pickIntent, documentPickerIntent)
    }

    /**
     * Create a chooser intent to select the source to get image from.<br></br>
     * The source can be camera's (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) or gallery's (ACTION_GET_CONTENT).<br></br>
     * All possible sources are added to the intent chooser.
     *
     * @param context          used to access Android APIs, like content resolve, it is your
     * activity/fragment/widget.
     * @param title            the title to use for the chooser UI
     * @param includeDocuments if to include KitKat documents activity containing all sources
     */
    private fun getPickImageChooserIntent(context: Context, title: CharSequence?, includeDocuments: Boolean, type: String = "image/*",
                                          extraIntents: ArrayList<Intent>? = null): Intent {
        val packageManager = context.packageManager
        var galleryIntents =
                getGalleryIntents(packageManager, Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, includeDocuments, type)
        if (galleryIntents.isEmpty()) {
            // if no intents found for get-content try pick intent action (Huawei P9).
            galleryIntents =
                    getGalleryIntents(packageManager, Intent.ACTION_PICK, includeDocuments, type)
        }
        val allIntents = ArrayList(galleryIntents)
        val target: Intent
        if (allIntents.isEmpty()) {
            target = Intent()
        } else {
            target = allIntents[allIntents.size - 1]
            allIntents.removeAt(allIntents.size - 1)
        }
        // Create a chooser from the main  intent
        val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(target, title)!!
        if (!extraIntents.isNullOrEmpty())
            allIntents.addAll(extraIntents)
        // Add all other intents
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toTypedArray<Parcelable>())
        return chooserIntent
    }

    /**
     * Get all Gallery intents for getting image from one of the apps of the device that handle
     * images. Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT and then Intent.ACTION_PICK
     */
    fun getGalleryIntents(packageManager: PackageManager, action: String, includeDocuments: Boolean, type: String = "image/*"): List<Intent> {
        val intents = ArrayList<Intent>()
        val galleryIntent = if (action == Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            Intent(action)
        else
            Intent(action, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        setTypesForIntent(galleryIntent, type)
        val listGallery = packageManager.queryIntentActivitiesCompat(galleryIntent)
        for (res in listGallery) {
            val intent = Intent(galleryIntent)
            intent.component = ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name)
            intent.`package` = res.activityInfo.packageName
            intents.add(intent)
        }
        // remove documents intent
        if (!includeDocuments) {
            for (intent in intents) {
                if (intent.component!!.className == "com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity") {
                    intents.remove(intent)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        return intents
    }
```