# View both Images and Videos in Device Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have the following requirement:

**From the mobile application , I want to open the default gallery of the Android tablet / device , which will contain both the image and video files and select them.**

Is there any option to view both image and video files on Android Gallery?

Kindly provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think, There is no such an option to open both images videos at a time..... But we can filter it before open like this

```
final CharSequence[] options = {"Images", "Videos", "Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OpenGallery.this);
        builder.setTitle("Select From...");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Images")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Videos")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this..

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
            "content://media/internal/images/media"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps ..!

Answer (score -2):

> try this

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("images/*,video/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Comment: Need to display image and video , not only image.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862483/android-open-gallery-and-choose-image-and-video