# How can i call android gallery with all media?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I know how to call gallery with only 1 type of data (images or video or audio), but not all together.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.TYPE.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY);
```

> android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI - images
>   android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI - video
>   android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI - audio

How can i call them "all at once"?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15862653/5743600

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use setType() on intent object.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("video/*, image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_PICK);
```