# Loading all images & videos from gallery in the app activity & selecting some of them

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, image-gallery, filechooser

I want to choose multiple media (videos or images) from gallery on clicking a button,
but only, after showing all the media from the gallery in activity of my app only,
(without opening my phone default gallery) & then, show them in the Recycler View (grid view).

Then, selecting images of Videos from them. I am a beginner in android,
also haven't find any help from other resources. Please guide me in the same & provide a proper solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862483/android-open-gallery-and-choose-image-and-video

Comment: "showing all the media from the gallery in activity of my app only" -- query the `MediaStore`. [This older sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/VideoList), covered in [this free older book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Android), demonstrates showing a list of videos obtained from the `MediaStore`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi I can understand your problem what you want is an **image/Video picker library** .its bad idea to build it on your own as a beginner so my recommendation would be to choose community build libraries which will make your job much easier

link of a few Image Picker libraries
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/157 you can google to find more libraries

follow the instruction from their Github page and try to implement them in your project it will be much easier

my recommendation would be to use this library **https://github.com/Mindinventory/Lassi-Android**
as this library provides both image and video to be picked

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped a lot. I just want to one thing, that are they libraries permanent ? Means if we use any library in our app, so will it work forever in the app ?

Comment: yeah! means libraries sometimes are not maintained by their owner hence they won't work on the long run but the library I shared is still being maintained and updated they are community-built and depends on the owner or contributors or even type of library you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can get list images and videos which is sorted by time, then you can show that in your adapter.

> Step 1:-Declare the variables

```
var image: ArrayList<FileMediaDetails>? = null
var video: ArrayList<FileMediaDetails>? = null
```

> Step 2:- create the funtion openDialog which is responsible for setup
> your adapter with recyclerview

```
    private fun openDialog() {
        val view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_gallery, null)
        val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme)
        dialog.setContentView(view)
        image = getData()
        video = getVideoList()
        val newSet: MutableSet<FileMediaDetails> = HashSet<FileMediaDetails>(image)
        newSet.addAll(video!!)
        val list = newSet.toList()

        var newList: List<FileMediaDetails> = ArrayList(newSet)
        newList = list.sortedWith(compareBy { it.dateModified })
        newList = newList.reversed()
//        Collections.shuffle(newList)
        dialog.rvImages.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        dialog.rvImages.adapter = ImagesAdapter(this, newList)
        dialog.rvImages.addOnItemTouchListener(
            RecyclerTouchListener(this, dialog.rvImages, RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener { _, position ->
                myFile = File(newList[position].path)
                uri = Uri.parse(newList[position].path)
                val extension = getMimeType(this, uri!!)
                if (extension == "mp4") {
                    if (isFileLessThan100MB(myFile!!)) // sending video
                        askDoubtWithUrl("video")
                    else
                        Utils.showToast(this, "Your file is too big to upload", AppConstant.FAILED)
                } else //  sending image
                    askDoubtWithUrl("image")
                dialog.dismiss()
            })
        )
        dialog.show()
    }
```

> Step 3:- getDatafor getting image list

```
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    private fun getData(): ArrayList<FileMediaDetails> {
//        val arrayList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        val arrayList: ArrayList<FileMediaDetails> = ArrayList()
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED)
        val cursor = contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null,
            null,
            null
        )
        while (cursor!!.moveToNext()) {
            val absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA))
            val createdTime = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED))
            arrayList.add(FileMediaDetails(absolutePathOfImage, createdTime))
        }
        cursor.close()
        return arrayList
    }
```

> Step 4 :- getVideoList for getting video list

```
private fun getVideoList(): ArrayList<FileMediaDetails> {
    val uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED)
    val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
    val pathArrList: ArrayList<FileMediaDetails> = ArrayList()
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(0)
            val createdTime = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED))
            pathArrList.add(FileMediaDetails(absolutePathOfImage,createdTime))
        }
        cursor.close()
    }
    return pathArrList
}
```